# Problem with TabbedPane in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

HY!

I want to create a TabbedPane with a jTable.

Designer:
[image]

Constructor Code in JForm:

```
    initComponents();
    this.add(jTabbedPane1);
    jTabbedPane1.addTab("Test", jPanel1);
    jPanel1.add(jTable1);
```

Auto-Gen-Code:

```
private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton_add = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(550, 300));

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"dddsds", null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 530, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 287, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jButton_add.setText("add");
        jButton_add.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        jButton_add.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton_addActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 579, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                        .addComponent(jButton_add)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton_add)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
```

Problem:

the jTable1 is invisible and the button is under the jTabbedPane and not under the jPanel.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add `jTable1` twice to `jPanel1`. `initComponents()` already adds `jScrollPane1` (which includes `jTable1`) to `jPanel1` through the use of `jPanel1Layout`. But in your constructor, you add `jTable1` a second time, explicitly to `jPanel1`. Hence your constructor should just be as follows:

```
initComponents();
this.add(jTabbedPane1);
jTabbedPane1.addTab("Test", jPanel1);
```

Note tha I've removed the line `jPanel1.add(jTable1);`

Then you have the same problem with jTabbedPane1, which is added twice to the content pane.

From the generated code I see, I would say you have probbably made some bad manipulation of Netbeans GUI designer, because `jTable1` is NOT inside `jTabbedPane1` but directly inside the content pane of the frame. I guess you should redesign your panel from scratch or at least modify your UI in the designer.

The important point to understand is that, when you use `GroupLayout` API, components are automatically added to their container and hence shouldn't be added explcitily.

My best advice, actually, would be: don't use NetBeands UI designer and code your UI by hand (but not with `GroupLayout` which is too complex to be coded manually).

Comment: Hello, just a comment, if the gui is simple it will work fine with netbeans, you can use it, and if the gui is rather complex write it by hand will be very complex, then you can use editor again, then I don't think that's a general advice to "write UI by hand", regards

Comment: I totally second your comment, except for the fact that "if the gui is simple" is something that almost never happens in real projects... Hence, one should always code GUIs by hand.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons:
1. jPanel1 has incorrect layout
2. `this` is wrong container.
3. jTable1 is not initialized properly.

just post more code ([sscce](http://sscce.org) if possible)

EDIT:
You should add the jScrollPane1 not table
Also See order layout.setHorizontalGroup()
you add jPanel1, JTabbedPane1, JButton_add.